# Higher time complexity but still faster

Tags: python, algorithm

I have two functions to check whether two words `word1` and `word2` are anagrams or not (note: two words are said to be anagrams if you can rearrange the letters of one of the words to get the other).

```py
def is_anagram(word1, wrod2):
    histogram = {}
    for char in word1:
        histogram[char] = histogram.get(char, 0) + 1
    # Trying to exhaust all the letters in a histogram by second word
    for char in word2:
        histogram[char] = histogram.get(char, 0) - 1
    for vals in histogram.values():
        if vals != 0: return False
    return True
```

Clearly, in the above function 3 loops are running so it has an overall complexity of *O(n)*

Here is the second implementation:

```py
def is_anagram2(word1, word2):
    sorted_word1 = ''.join(sorted(word1))
    sorted_word2 = ''.join(sorted(word2))
    return sorted_word1 == sorted_word2
```

The `sorted` function has a complexity of *nlogn*, so the complexity of this function should be *O(nlogn)*.

But still if you measure the execution time of theses two functions (e.g. through timeit command in ipython), it is found that the `is_anagram2` function is faster.

Please explain why...

Comment: Can you show us the test cases you're using and the times you're seeing?

Comment: Also I suppose that `c = collections.Counter(word1); c.subtract(word2); return bool(+c)` will be even faster:) The reason is that `sorted` is a builtin implemented in pure C, while your loop is in python and thus has a massive loop overhead. `logn` multiple is almost nothing for any input that you can invent, so having almost all work done in C dominates it.

Comment: It would be even faster if you didn't do the *join()*. *return sorted(word1) == sorted(word2)* will suffice

Comment: `10000n` is greater than `0.00001nlogn`, for small enough values of `n`.  Big-O tells you *rate of growth*, not exact runtime.

Comment: in second function you don't need to convert string to lists and back to strings: use one return line instead:
    `return sorted(word1) == sorted(word2)`

Comment: in first function you don't need the third for loop: just use two dicts and compare them: `return histogram1 == histogram2`

Comment: @AK-CHP - if would be very helpful to see your *sample inputs* along with the measurement *timeit* results to support the arguments.  People can review and supplement with more data points later...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because the second function is leaving all the important work to the underlying native code of the Python interpreter (namely, the `sorted` function). The first function is instead doing everything in Python code, breaking the task into smaller operations.

Python ([CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython) at least, which is the official implementation) is implemented in C, and C code is an order of magnitude faster than Python code. This is because C is optimized and compiled to machine code that runs directly on your CPU. On the other hand, Python code runs *on top of a virtual machine implemented in C* (the Python interpreter): it has to be parsed, turned into [Python bytecode](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-bytecode), and then every single bytecode operation needs to be executed by the interpreter, which is much slower.

This is a common problem that will come up countless times when optimizing for performance in Python. Sometimes it is just better to leave native code do the job because the overhead of Python bytecode outweighs its advantages. This is also the reason why libraries such as [NumPy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/index.html) are very popular: they implement most of the functionality in C, and only expose high level APIs through Python modules, so they can be very efficient for certain tasks if used correctly instead of plain Python code.